# ValueError when execution .transform on empty DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After upgrading Pandas from 1.1.5 to 1.2.x `.transform` stops working on empty DataFrames.

Some things that could be done to avoid the issue, but it will be too costly for me to do because will require me to change too many places in my project:

- Add a `.empty` test before the transform
- Replace with `.apply` method works (I was expecting that transform would be able to handle empty DataFrames like `apply` do)

Is there a way to make it work?

The following codes (with `df1` and `df2`) works fine on 1.1.5 but it fails in 1.2.x:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame([{"id": 1, "name": "Test"}], columns=["id", "name"])
   ...: df1["id"].transform(lambda x: x + 10)

Out[1]: 
0    11
Name: id, dtype: int64

In [2]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([], columns=["id", "name"])
   ...: df2["id"].transform(lambda x: x + 10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8b3376edd7eb> in <module>
      1 df2 = pd.DataFrame([], columns=["id", "name"])
----> 2 df2["id"].transform(lambda x: x + 10)

~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/envs/odds-data/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in transform(self, func, axis, *args, **kwargs)
   3975         self, func: AggFuncType, axis: Axis = 0, *args, **kwargs
   3976     ) -> FrameOrSeriesUnion:
-> 3977         return transform(self, func, axis, *args, **kwargs)
   3978 
   3979     def apply(self, func, convert_dtype=True, args=(), **kwds):

~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/envs/odds-data/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/aggregation.py in transform(obj, func, axis, *args, **kwargs)
    458     # when the dtype is not appropriate
    459     if isinstance(result, (ABCSeries, ABCDataFrame)) and result.empty:
--> 460         raise ValueError("Transform function failed")
    461     if not isinstance(result, (ABCSeries, ABCDataFrame)) or not result.index.equals(
    462         obj.index

ValueError: Transform function failed
```

Comment: Maybe a bug. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Comment: I asked on Pandas Gitter room and one of the contributors mentioned that it looks like a regression bug. Opened https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39636 so I hope that I will have the right answer there.